# Wildcard parameter value and zend navigation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

Is it posible to map a page to a specific action + param combination, like this:

```
                    <myprofile>
                        <label>My Profile</label>
                        <controller>user</controller>
                        <action>profile</action>
                        <visible>1</visible>
                    </myprofile>                    
                    <othersprofile>
                        <label>User Profile</label>
                        <controller>usuario</controller>
                        <action>perfil</action>
                        <visible>0</visible>
                        <reset_params>0</reset_params>
                        <params>
                            <id>*</id>
                        </params>
                    </othersprofile>
```

I'd like that if the uri includes any id param , then the  should be active. (I put a * as wildcard but I dont know a correct way to do it)

/user/profile = should set myprofile to active
/user/profile/id/5 = should set othersprofile to active

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround by setting explicitly the page as active in your action.

You could do it like this :

```
public function perfilAction(){
    $this->view->navigation()->findOneBy('controller','usario')->setActive();

    // rest of your action code...
```

Starting from ZF 1.11.8, you should be able to just add the route name in your page params, and it will be active for anything matching this route. (the "route" feature has been added before, but there were some issues with isActive detection, see http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11359)